# How to remove base64 encoding for emails sent from web app

Tags: c#, email, encoding

I'm Developing a ASP.NET web application. One feature sends out "forgot password" emails.

My client complains that they cannot view the email because their webmail client supports RFC standards and can't read base64 encoded formatted emails (because apparently this is not an RFC Standard.)

I didn't see anywhere in my code where I was explicitly set anything to base64. So I changed the c# code to try and force it to not be base64....

A portion of the code....

```
mail.Body = messageBody;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
mail.BodyTransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.SevenBit;
mail.Headers.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "7BIT");
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

I receive the email ok. But when I dig into the email I see this (partial snippet)....

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=-xxxxxxx=="

--=-xxxxxx==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

xxxxxx

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  version="2.0">
```

As you can see "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" still shows up, even though I'm setting the TransferEncoding in 2 places in my code. I'm not sure why. Any suggestions on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although "the customer is always right" and it doesn't provide a solution to your problem, do note that your client is talking nonsense: `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` is defined in RFC 1341 (MIME) which is 28 years old as of writing. That doesn't preclude things having no support for it (or probably more accurately, not supporting mails that don't have a 7-bit text body in addition to whatever MIME parts they might have), but claiming it's somehow not a standard is ludicrous. I suspect you'll find it impossible to satisfy their desires as long as you use `IsBodyHtml = true`.

Comment: Very Interesting!